# My numpy array is 4D when i expect it to be a 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, computer-vision

I'm very new to computer vision so please bear with my dumb doubts :/

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/newtest/*.png")
for myFile in files:
    #print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

#print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data))

print(np.array(X_data).shape)
```

This outputs me a value of (5103, 28, 28, 3)

My path contains number of .png files and they are grayscale of size 28x28
I expect numpy array of shape[5103,28,28]

Comment: three color channels. If they're greyscale just do `X_data = X_data[...,0]`

Comment: @kevinkayaks, thanks! understood

Answer (score 0):

The image format probably contains more color channels, try something like:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
```

Would need the image file to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell to `cv2.imread` that you want a greyscale version loaded in memory using the optional flag `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. You can find some example [here](https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-read-image-cv2-imread/).

Note that you can create the final array with `np.empty` with the right shape ahead of time and fill it iteratively in order to save some memory and time.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
image = cv2.imread (myFile)
```

to this:

```
image = cv2.imread (myFile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

It will read 1-channel image instead of 3-channel